# Wordpress Hide Widget If $_Session Is Active?

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if there is an easy solution to add some php "if" code when my website tries to show the widgets and if it has $_SESSION I set on homepage (based on the source of which they came) not to show one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe [this](http://blog.rutwick.com/show-or-hide-a-wp-widget-only-on-specific-pages) will answer your question.

You finally could have something like this:

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'hidemywidget' );

function hidemywidget($all_widgets) {
    if( $_SESSION['%your key%'] == '%your value%' ) {
        foreach ( $all_widgets['primary-widget-area'] as $i => $inst ) {
            $pos = strpos( $inst, '%the widget you want to hide%');

            if( $pos !== false ) {
                unset( $all_widgets['primary-widget-area'][$i] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $all_widgets;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look and try to implement it, It does seem like what I need =)

Comment: I was able to use your code and it works perfectly you're the best!